# Git how to rebase onto empty branch for code reviews

Tags: git, rebase, github-codereviews

I'm following this recipe: https://thib.me/recipe-code-reviews-for-existing-code-with-github. In the interactive rebase step, I'm adding a `pick` line for the empty commit created in `review-1-target` repository as the first line in the rebase instructions file. However, there are merge conflicts.

How can I conduct the rebase so that merge conflicts are resolved exactly as they were in the original history given that the base is an empty commit?

Answer (score -3):

Can you try if this helps to undo local changes

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/<branch name>
git clean -f -d
```

Comment: There should be a clear warning here that these commands will delete local changes. Can you detail in your answer how this helps solve the OP's issue? Currently your answer is unclear and perhaps would be more suitable as a comment.